# Python attribute error when using JSON

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code in a file called grab.py

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=googleplex&sensor=false"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```

But when I run it I get this error:

```
File "grab.py", line 1, in <module>                                   

    import urllib, json
File "/home/cabox/workspace/json.py", line 3, in <module>             
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

Comment: There is a `json.py` in your current directory?

Comment: Works for me (printout is `{u'status': u'ZERO_RESULTS', u'results': []}`).